# Strophe session termination due to RID skip

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I have a phonegap application developed which uses strophe.js to communicate with our own XMPP server.The session is etstablished once the user has logged in and in the subsequent screen's the attach() function is used to attach to the same session.The attach in itself works fine there is no disconnection or rid miss when i navigate from screen to screen ,but the problem is when i am on  a particular screen for a long time, randomly the strophe misses an rid for the bind packet as result of which the session is terminated.Can some one pls point me how to go about solving this, as i don know what is causing this.Any pointers would be appreciated.